# Populating month and day

Tags: c#

I'm populating a combobox with month name as follows:`

```
        var engCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");            
        cmbAmCul.Items.AddRange(engCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames);
```

what is the right way to:

1. eliminate the blank entry after the
   12 month names.
2. populate another
       combobox with day (1-31 || 1-28 ||
       1-30) according to the month
       selected?

Comment: May i ask why do you need that? It seems that you are trying to make a control to let the user pick a date, which seems unnecessary to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the first part, you could use a linq query...

```
var engCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");            
cmbAmCul.Items.AddRange(from m in engCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames 
                        where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(m) 
                        select m);
```

The DateTimeInfo class supports calendars with 13 months, which is why this occurs.

For the second part, I would go for something like...

```
for (int i = 1; i <= DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month); i++) {
    cmbDay.Items.Add(i.ToString());
}
```

Obviously populating the year/month vars from your selected values.

Comment: The first is giving error:
"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: Yeah, it works fine.  Can you confirm you are targetting .NET 3.5 with your project, and have a "using System.Linq" at the top of your page?

Answer (score 3):

1. Use String.Trim() to remove blanks from beginning & end of strings
2. Use return value from `DateTime.DaysInMonth(int year, int month)` to populate your day combo box

You could also use a DateTime picker from the standard controls or is it not an option for you?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify what you are trying to build (ASP.NET or Winforms etc) but you could possibly use a Calendar control instead of dropdowns to improve the User experience.  Less clicks and less code tho go wrong perhaps.